# Unable to find Xamarin Live Player on iTunes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-live-player

I'm am developing an iOS app on a Windows machine and I want to debug on the physical device. I know that the Xamarin Live Player suits my needs but, I can't download the app from the Turkish App Store. It says:

> The item you've requested is not currently available in the Turkish Store

I've also tried U.S. store but the result is the same.

Is there any way that I can download Xamarin Live Player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not in the App Store for iOS but you can sign up for the TestFlight access [here](https://aka.ms/liveplayeralpha)

> We encourage users to join the Xamarin Live Player app iOS Preview to
>   enjoy quick access to the latest improvements through TestFlight.

Once you sign up [here](https://aka.ms/liveplayeralpha) you will then need to fill out the fastlane registration.

After that, you will receive an email with the TestFlight code. 
Download TestFlight to the device enter the code and download the Live Player

like so:
[image]

Once downloaded continue with step 2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/install?tabs=ios%2Cmacos)

Comment: They have broken the link somehow, check this issue for updates https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/307

Comment: Thank you for pointing to that, I will follow the issue there.

Comment: it is working back again, thank you for pointing to this issue thread.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Comment: fastlane registration not working >> "Something went wrong, please contact the application owner: Unauthorized Access"

Comment: Well, the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations clearly mentions the following:

iOS
Live Player is not available for iOS.

Comment: Well that’s new?! Wonder why it has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, as of 8/7/2018, Xamarin Live Player is not available on iOS.
(I would imagine Apple rejected this wonderful tool)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations

[image]

Comment: Nothing wonderful about it, never worked for me and many many many others.  Neither for Android, nor iOS.  Worked briefly 2 yrs ago and that was it

Comment: It worked for simple XAML, however been crashing lately. Wish Microsoft open sourced it so we can deploy our own LivePlayer

Comment: @Yah, perfect solution for real world, simple XAML.